# Install configparser error on windows 7

Tags: python, configuration, module, installation, pip

When i install module configparser on windows 7 using command "pip install ConfigParser", I receive an error:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

> E:\KIENNH\projects\Projs\acs>pip install ConfigParser
>   Downloading/unpacking ConfigParser   Downloading
>   configparser-3.3.0r2.tar.gz   Running setup.py
>   (path:C:***\ConfigParser\setup.py) egg_info for package ConfigParser
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 3, in 
>         File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools__init__.py", line 5, in 
>           import distutils.core
>         File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 18, in 
>           from distutils.config import PyPIRCCommand
>         File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\config.py", line 7, in 
>           from configparser import ConfigParser
>         File "C:***\ConfigParser\configparser.py", line 397
>           _KEYCRE = re.compile(ur"%(([^)]+))s")
>                                                ^
>       SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 3, in
>
> File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools__init__.py", line 5,
>   in
>
> ```
> import distutils.core
> ```
>
> File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 18, in
>
> ```
> from distutils.config import PyPIRCCommand
> ```
>
> File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\config.py", line 7, in
>
> ```
> from configparser import ConfigParser
> ```
>
> File "C:***\configparser.py", line 397
>
> ```
> _KEYCRE = re.compile(ur"%\(([^)]+)\)s")
>
>                                      ^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Ps: I have found a similar question here, but there no answer!:
https://github.com/flyingrub/scdl/issues/8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`configparser` is included in the standard library.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

Just use `import configparser`